# Good way to tell a user why my web app doesn't support Internet Explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, web-applications, browser

As you all know internet explorer sucks:), so I will probably never want to write code for it.

Are they some nice text out there that explains to a random visitor why he shouldn't use Internet Explorer?

E.g. http://www.ie6nomore.com/ and http://code.google.com/p/ie6-upgrade-warning/ are nice but doesn't explain to the user why he shouldn't use IE.

Thanks!

Edit: yes all IE versions, IE9 is still behind the alternatives, see http://people.mozilla.com/~prouget/ie9/ and http://people.mozilla.com/~prouget/ie9/ie9_vs_fx4.html

Edit-edit: I'm NOT asking if I should or not support IE, I'm only asking for a kind text explaining why Internet Explorer shouldn't be used.

Comment: Do you mean all IE browsers? You will lose > 50% of your vistors at least I should think. Man up and take the pain.

Comment: right now on my question asking about a text describing why IE sucks stackoverflow is showing me an ad for IE9 -_-

Comment: IE has actually gotten a lot better since version 6.  I'm still no fan of it by any means, but it's probably worth the effort to support it.  What about your web app doesn't support it?  Is it just CSS quirks?  Chances are, the problem is solvable.

Comment: IE8 is a pretty good browser.  Most of the pain you had to deal with in IE6 is gone.  You can alleviate most of the remaining pain by using cross-browser libraries like jQuery.

Comment: @Robert,Richard,David: please stick to the topic. IE is lacking APIs i need like CORS

Comment: Then say that. Why mince words?  There's no good way to say to a user that you're not supporting a browser that 43% of the people on the planet are using  (including me, *right now*).

Comment: But you have a reason, otherwise you wouldn't be so certain about what you are asking here. So why ask us what the reason is? I'm not really sure what you are asking. Do we need to tell you why you should not support IE, even though most of us think you should? I'm really confused at that....

Answer (score 3):

**Millions of employees of large corporations have no control over the browser on their machine.** The companies don't allow them to change browsers (no admin rights on their machines).

If you anticipate that any of your users may attempt to use your website while they are at work, you will surely antagonize them (and reveal your ignorance) by telling them to change to a different browser. There is no "nice text" that you can use that will change their situation.

Answer (score 3):

Tell them

**"The developer of this site is a very tenacious guy. Though a lot of people told him that he will exclude about 50% of his possible audience, he still refuses to support Internet Explorer since he is convinced that this thing sucks and likes to participate in this holy war."**

At least, that statement will be honest.

By the way, I recommend reading Joel's article [Martian Headsets](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/items/2008/03/17.html), perhaps this will give you a different view on your topic.

Comment: +1 for the Martian Headsets link.  Very good read.

Answer (score 0):

According to StatCounter IE still commands around 45% of market share. No matter whether it sucks or whatever, would you like to shoo away half of your customers.

Based on your website and demographic, it could be that IE is used by more than half of your user base. You got to support them!

Comment: It's more like 43%.  You're probably not counting all versions of IE.  See here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Usage_share_of_web_browsers

Comment: The statistics you reported are about w3schools users, so a particular (and small) part of all users of the web (technically more prepared)

Comment: @Robert - Cross checked myself and updated my answer.

Comment: I'm not sure the statistics reported there can be regarded as representative of all browser use. On the bottom of the page it says "The statistics above are extracted from W3Schools' log-files, but we are also monitoring other sources around the Internet to assure the quality of these figures." You are going to get more tech-savvy users going to the W3Schools web site than your average user and technical users will tend to favour a non-IE browser.

Comment: Right from the page you linked to - "W3Schools is a website for people with an interest for web technologies. These people are more interested in using alternative browsers than the average user. The average user tends to the browser that comes preinstalled with their computer, and do not seek out other browser aternatives.

These facts indicate that the browser figures above are not 100% realistic. Other web sites have statistics showing that Internet Explorer is a more popular browser."

Comment: off topic, guys please stick to the topic

Comment: W3Schools is **not** the W3C and their statistics represent their own users (who haven't realised how bad they are — http://w3fools.com/ ) not users in general.